# MYSQL creating a trigger to sum total amount on insert and update

Tags: mysql, triggers, sum, mysql-workbench

I am using MYSQL 6.0 Workbench to create my trigger.

I have a table storing amount spent on maintenance for vehicles.  I would like to create a trigger, that on update and insert of the columns, it will sum up all the values and populate the already existing TOTAL column with the calculated sum.  I want these values to be stored in the table rather than running a query.

table = Inventory_maintenance (oil_change, brakes, belts, other, total)
All values are doubles.  My table is currently empty, awaiting data.

These are the triggers I have tried so far:

```
USE `car_db`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `inventory_maintenance_AINS`
                AFTER INSERT ON `inventory_maintenance`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET inventory_maintenance.TOTAL =
          inventory_maintenance.OIL_CHANGE
        + inventory_maintenance.BELTS
        + inventory_maintenance.BRAKES
        + inventory_maintenance.OTHER ;
END#
```

**ERRORS**:

```
ERROR 1193: Unknown system variable 'TOTAL'
ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
ERROR 1050: Table 'inventory_maintenance' already exists**
```

and.....

```
USE `car_db`;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `inventory_maintenance_AINS`
               AFTER INSERT ON `inventory_maintenance`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.TOTAL = NEW.OIL_CHANGE + NEW.BELTS + NEW.BRAKES + NEW.OTHER; 
END#
```

**ERRORS**:

```
ERROR 1362: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger
ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.
ERROR 1050: Table 'inventory_maintenance' already exists**
```

Where am I going wrong?  Forgive me but I am new to triggers.

Answer (score 0):

The `AFTER` trigger fires only *after* completion of DML operation. The scope of `NEW` would be until completion of the DML operation.

Please refer to:  [*AFTER triggers start; no values can be altered...*](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,84452,84495#msg-84495)

> 1. *Insert executes with values of NEW row; data is written to the table*.
> 2. *AFTER triggers start; no values can be altered, since they have been written to the table already, but other operations can be executed from the trigger, for example to insert/update/delete rows in other tables*.
> 3. *Control is returned to application*.

If you really want to set values of column in the new row, use `BEFORE` trigger.
Following should be working.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `inventory_maintenance_BINS`
               BEFORE INSERT ON `inventory_maintenance`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.TOTAL = NEW.OIL_CHANGE + NEW.BELTS + NEW.BRAKES + NEW.OTHER; 
END#

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Tried what you suggested and now it doesn't give me a syntax error before applying the changes but now I get these errors:  ERROR 1054: Unknown column 'TOTAL' in 'NEW' and that the inventory table already exists

Comment: I am not sure on why it is throwing such error. I suggest you contact your database admin on this.

Comment: Or, if it is safe, take a backup of the said table, drop and rebuild it with backed-up data. And then try running your trigger script.

Comment: This is my home computer and database not at work.  So essentially I am my own database admin lol...  In the "how to" it uses the command prompt and it is different syntax than what workbench gives me: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/trigger-syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `inventory_maintenance_BINS`
               BEFORE INSERT ON `inventory_maintenance`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.TOTAL = NEW.OIL_CHANGE + NEW.BELTS + NEW.BRAKES + NEW.OTHER; 
END#

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

or you can try this :

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `inventory_maintenance_BINS`
               AFTER INSERT ON `inventory_maintenance`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET inventory_maintenance.TOTAL = inventory_maintenance.OIL_CHANGE + inventory_maintenance.BELTS + inventory_maintenance.BRAKES + inventory_maintenance.OTHER; 
END#

$$

DELIMITER ;
```

The tag "New" cannot be used on after insert trigger.